# WinForms. ошибка в исходных библиотеках

Tags: winforms

дали задание по курсовой работе. В моменте все работало, но стоило мне написать 4 строчки все сломалось, после чего я убрал все написанные раннее строчки, но ошибки все равно остались, и все они в исходных файлах. Не знаю в чем дело. Также попробовал прогуглить все ошибки по их кодам, но все ссылки не решают проблему.[image: Вот список ошибок]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: С такой формулировкой вопроса далеко не уедите

Comment: я начал писать код для обработчика загрузки окна, до этого, а именно когда я создавал в конструкторе элементы, у меня не было ни единой проблемы.
private: System::Void AddRecipe_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
 std::string color = get_color();
 std::string lang = _get_language();
}
вот так выглядит код из-за которого все сломалось

Comment: `^` - управляемый (managed) указатель. `*` - неуправляемый/нативный (unmanaged/native) указатель. Судя по ошибкам, последний применён к первому. / Как исправить? Отказаться от C++/CLI. Учите либо чистый C++, либо C#.

Comment: проблема заключалась в этом. я использовал библиотеку, где был прописан неуправляемый указатель. но у меня встречный вопрос: какие можно использовать структуры данных, чтобы не появлялось этого вновь, за исключением массивов(одномерных, двумерных и тд)?